# Flutter - problem with multiple call of didChangeAppLifecycleState

Tags: flutter

I need to use didChangeAppLifecycleState method to do some actions on resuming application but I encountered on some problems with multi calls of this function.

Code I use in didChangeAppLifecycleState method:

```
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      setState(() {
        print('didChangeAppLifecycleState');
      });
    }
  }
```

Steps to reproduce:

- go to /home (where is called didChangeAppLifecycleState method)
- pause application (minimize)
- run app - console print single `I/flutter (26680): didChangeAppLifecycleState`
- go to some other view (Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('something'))
- pause app (minimize)
- run app
- go again on /home route
- pause app (minimize)
- run app - console print twice `I/flutter (26680): didChangeAppLifecycleState`

Comment: what do you mean by a pause here? please describe

Comment: I mean minimizing app